# How to set the pivot point for an object that is made by multiple objects in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I used a skin editor to create the bone structure for a psb file,

[image]

the character is in the centre of the canvas but when I tried to flip it by scale it changes position.

[image]

I guess the gray ball in the picture is the pivot point so I googled how to change the pivot but the tutorials are all for a single game object. And I don't know why the flip in the sprite render didn't change anything. Here is my setup

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A gameObject's parent's position *is* it's pivot point. So if you want to change the pivot point of your sprite, select all the children (all the gameobjects nested under "player_side_shadow"), and change their positions. When you change the position of a child, you're changing it's *relative* or *local* position in relation to its parent: its pivot point (when you rotate the parent).

[image: select and change the position of the children]

#### edit

As pointed out by derHugo: if the sprite(s) are already animated then you don't want to break existing frames. Instead you would apply the same process but add *another* parent (an empty gameobject) over everything, and rotate/flip that new parent.

Comment: This might be an issue if they are already animated -> you would need to change all animations accordingly. However, you could also simply take it as it is and place it yet under a new parent object, move the current one where needed relative to that new parent and  instead flip that parent object